# I'll bring you to your mother's

Tags: grammar

> I'll bring you to your mother's
>
> I'll take you to your mother's

I am a bit confuse of these.

Should it bring or take?

Comment: “Bring” usually means to the place where the speaker is located. “Take” usually means to another place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of them could work there. And both have a very similar meaning when used to mean that you want to guide someone to a particular place. There is an important difference between these two verbs, however.

Bringing someone somewhere would be a situation where you're not asking them whether they want to go there or not. You just either physically make them go there or you use other nonphysical factors to influence their decision to go there. It has a connotation of physically taking and carrying someone somewhere like an object. Here's an example:

> Find the bastard that killed my brother and **bring** him to me alive!

Taking someone somewhere, on the other hand, has the idea that the people you're taking somewhere are going there of their own accord. In other words, they're not forced to go there. For example:

> — Do you know where she lives?
>   — Yes, I do. She lives on Houston Street. It's not far from here.
>   — Can you **take** me there?

Comment: "Can I take me there?" doesn't make sense, as take implies an additional object. "Can you take me there?" would serve as a better example.

Comment: I'm sorry. It's supposed to be **you**. Thank you for pointing that out.